# Error in embedded service config when I try to deploy it

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, embedded-services

When I try to deploy my bot I have this error:

`EmbeddedServiceConfig/chat_test.EmbeddedServiceConfig -- Error: In field: U#745.cff (CustomLabel) - no CustomLabel named LA_Waiting_WithoutQueuePos_WaitingGreeting_04I7Z000000Cb68_1448821 found&#xa;&#xa`

But in chat_test.EmbeddedServiceConfig.xml there is this custom label and also there is in the custom label metadata.

How can I resolve it?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try to deploy the custom label alone first , then the bot ?

Comment: the custom label is part of the bot, they are in the embedded service of the bot, so i can't. I have this problem only with this label...